# Badge number not updating in UrbanAirShip

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, urbanairship.com

I am new to iOS.

- I am using urban Airship for push notification.
- Now when I send notification for the first time I got badge 1.
- But when I again send the notification it still reamins to +1 though
  I send notification with +1 badge.

I use

```
[[UAPush shared] setAutobadgeEnabled:YES];
[[UAPush shared] resetBadge];
```

in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method.

Thanks

Comment: is your badge counter a local-auto variable?

Comment: no Number is maintain to server

Comment: is its count increasing?

Comment: when first notification comes it gives me 1. But after that it is not incrementing

Comment: As you said, you are using some-push notification, and the Number which is supposed to be the badge count is stored in server. And it gets increased only for 1st, after this it is not getting increased at all?

Comment: Yes you are perfectly right

Comment: So from where you are increasing it? Through your program or somewhere else?

Comment: Actually from documents from the official website of Urban Airship i came to know that the server is capable to make count of notification. When sending Notification from website we can write +1 or -1 by that it can provide us increment in count. But it is not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21206/discussion-between-user1162056-and-anoop-vaidya)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notifications always set the badge number to the value sent. There is no incrementing. If you send no value, then the badge mains unchanged on what it was previously. If you send 0, then the badge is removed.

Looking at the documentation I find that you have to supply the correct value for the badge parameter: supported are auto,increment and decrement. Those take the recent value from UA's database and modify it according to the keyword.

This is something you need to do in the push notification JSON dictionary.

PS: you should check out our app Airship Commander when it gets approved by Apple. This has a stepper control to leave, erase or set the badge number: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/12/airship-commander-1-0/

Comment: That's true, but s/he's using Urban Airship, which does do incrementing badge numbers. See the section on setting badge numbers: https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Server:+iOS+Push+API#ServeriOSPushAPI